# Removing noise using a control sample

Tags: noise

[image]

I have some measurements of displacement vs time of movement of a particle. Between these measurements, I have some particles that are supposed to not be moving at all (these are the control samples). Therefore, all my measurements have noise.

I would like to remove this noise by using the control samples; the measurements I'm having from my control samples are supposed to be pure noise while graph P2 is real displacement+noise.

Is there any method that I can use to remove this noise using my control samples?

thanks

Comment: How? Are the noises correlated? Such that the control and non-control samples move in similar directions? Or is noise completely random?

Comment: completely random noise

Comment: Can you post an example plot of such movements between control and non control samples?

Comment: sure @user2974951. this is a link with two plots. the one in the left is the control one.

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/1060/RLv2m4.png

Comment: This helps, also, you can post images in your question using the edit button. Based on this graphs I cannot really see any patterns, it seems to be moving pretty randomly through time, the control sample has slightly less variation than the non control sample. I don't know if this can be done. Why are you trying to remove noise anyway?

Comment: thanks, I'd like to remove noise to measure the real displacements. My source noise is due to a code I wrote in MatLab based on the function "imfindcircles". My code recognize circular features in a video, the code succesfully recognizes the circles in every frame; however, the recognized circles are not well centered and there are slightly moved even for the control samples.

Comment: I can't think of any methods for this. My attempt would be to decompose these series and remove the residuals.

Comment: Thanks @user2974951. The question was updated with new data and plots. I took new measurements and I did obtain much better data. Sadly, I'm still not sure how to remove this noise. This time it is clear that control and non-control samples move in the similar direction, both increasing. –

Comment: Well, since they all seem to be moving in the same direction, you can estimate the trend in the control group and then subtract this from the non-control samples.

Comment: many thanks. this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments, since your data seems to be following a very nice (mostly) straight path, you can estimate the trend in your data - the controls, such as via simple linear regression, and then subtract this from your non-control samples.

Alternatively, since all the samples seem to be on the same scale, you could also subtract the trend by decomposing each time series individually, and retaining only the seasonal and remainders.

Comment: thanks again. Just to be sure that I did the right thing. The "x" axis is the same for samples and controls. So for every "i" value, being "i" the time, I calculated the mean from the controls. Then from the main samples I subtsratced the calculated mean (the one from the controls).

Comment: @Ivan I wouldn't do it like that, what I would do is estimate the mean slope and intercept for all the control samples together (unless you did a paired experiment, that is one control vs. non control), similar to what calculated in the image you posted (`y=0.0025x-0.05`), except this would be an aggregate for all the control samples. Then you use this formula to subtract the average slope from your non control samples, since you can calculate the average value of this function at any point.